# Pass the uploaded file to asp.net events using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am Currently developing a application using asp.net c#. I have a requirement where i have a two html File upload control and some textbox.

I have used jquery to post the data from aspx to aspx.cs page. Currently i am unable to post the data uploaded in the file control.

Below is my code.
aspx page

```
    <input type="file" name="filUpload" id="filUpload" onchange="showimagepreview(this)" />
    <img id="imgprvw" alt="uploaded image preview" width="94px" height="75px" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
            function showimagepreview(input) {
//code to preview the file as soon as you select the file via file upload control       
         if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                    var filerdr = new FileReader();
                    filerdr.onload = function (e) {
                        $('#imgprvw').attr('src', e.target.result);
                    }
                    filerdr.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
                    alert($("#filUpload").val());

                    var formData = new FormData();
                    formData.append('file', $('#filUpload')[0].files[0]);

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "Testing.aspx/GetFile",
                        data:  What should be passed here // "{Files: '" + $('#filUpload')[0].files[0] + "'}",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (Result) {
                            alert('success')
                        },
                        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert(xhr.responseText);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        </script>
```

aspx.cs page

```
[WebMethod, ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = false)]
        public static void GetFile(object Files)
        {
              //What should be done here so that i can get the details of the file that has been selected via file upload control
        }
```

Has been stuck on this since long. Let me know if there is some way to handle this.

Comment: Using file handler to do this.

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/47244/uploading-files-using-jquery-ajax-in-Asp-Net.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It helped me to do my task in a different approach